# Trying to create a function to sum odd integers

Tags: ruby

Trying to get this program to ask for  numbers and then add the odd integers. Looking to link the prompt with the function.

```
puts("give me numbers")
gets = numbers
def oddball_sum(numbers)
   i = 0
    while i < numbers.length
    if (numbers[i]%2!=0)
      result += numbers[i]
     i+=1 
   end
  return result
  end
  end
```

Comment: `gets` returns a string, not an array of integers. When you want to extract the integers from the string then you have to do that first. How do you input the integers? Separated by whitespace? By commas?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples to sum a list of odd integers:
First the minimal changes to get your code working.

```
puts("give me numbers") 
numbers = gets.split.map {_1.to_i}
def oddball_sum(numbers)
    result = 0
   i = 0
    while i < numbers.length
        if (numbers[i]%2!=0)
        result += numbers[i]
        end
        i+=1
    end
    return result
end
puts oddball_sum(numbers)
```

1. You had gets and numbers swapped,  you want to get the string and save it in numbers.
2. You need to split the string based on some separator. You did not answer @spickermann's question so I assumed spaces.
3. You need to define result outside the `if` statement
4. You need to move the `return result` to after the loop completes

Then two more versions

```
puts("give me numbers")
numbers = gets.split.map { _1.to_i }
odd_numbers = numbers.select { _1.odd? }
sum_of_odds = odd_numbers.sum 
puts sum_of_odds

puts("give me numbers")
sum_of_odds = gets        # get a line from the terminal
    .split                # split the line based on spaces, this creates an array of strings
    .map { _1.to_i }      # map each string value to an interger value
    .select { _1.odd? }   # filter the array to only the odd values
    .sum                  # sum up the remaining values
puts sum_of_odds
```

Comment: I can't seem to get the fixed up version of the original code to format correctly

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

```
puts("give me numbers")
gets              # read user input: `"1,2,3,4 5"`
  .scan(/\d+/)    # extract numbers from input: `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]`
  .map(&:to_i)    # translate numbers to integers: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
  .select(&:odd?) # select all odd values: `[1, 3, 5]`
  .sum            # sum the remaining values in the array: `9`

# give me numbers
# input: 1,2,3,4 5
# => 9
```